# Checking if an ArrayList contains a certain String while being case insensitive

Tags: java, arraylist

How can i search through an ArrayList using the .contains method while being case insensitive? I've tried .containsIgnoreCase but found out that the IgnoreCase method only works for Strings.

Here's the method I'm trying to create:

```
 private ArrayList<String> Ord = new ArrayList<String>(); 

 public void leggTilOrd(String ord){
     if (!Ord.contains(ord)){
         Ord.add(ord);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Very unclear. Complete your code

Comment: try to iterate over list in search for your string

Comment: what do you mean by .containsIgnoreCase but found out that it only works for Strings??

Comment: That the IgnoreCase method only works for Strings and not ArrayLists.

Comment: @VictorSorokin don't try it, just do it :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need to iterate over the list and check each element. This is what is happening in the `contains` method. Since you are wanting to use the `equalsIgnoreCase` method instead of the `equals` method for the String elements you are checking, you will need to do it explicitly. That can either be with a for-each loop or with a Stream (example below is with a Stream).

```
private final List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

public void addIfNotPresent(String str) {
    if (list.stream().noneMatch(s -> s.equalsIgnoreCase(str))) {
        list.add(str);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Java7, simply override the contains() method,

```
public class CastInsensitiveList extends ArrayList<String> {
    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object obj) {
        String object = (String)obj;
        for (String string : this) {
            if (object.equalsIgnoreCase(string)) {
              return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

If you are using Java 8.0, using streaming API,

```
List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
arrayList.stream().anyMatch(string::equalsIgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 2):

The `List#Ccontains()` method check if  the parameter is present in the list but no changes are made in the list elements

use streams instead

```
public void leggTilOrd(String ordParameter) {
    final List<String> ord = Arrays.asList(new String[]{ "a", "A", "b" });
    final boolean ordExists = ord.stream().anyMatch(t -> t.equalsIgnoreCase(ordParameter));
    System.out.println(ordExists);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid duplicates use `HashSet` instead of List. Hashing works faster while searching. In the underlying class override the equals and hashcode method to return expected results using `String.toUpperCase()`. If you have a List of String, you can create a string wrapper class.

String Wrapper could look like this:-

```
public class CaseInsensitiveString {

    String string;

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((string == null) ? 0 : string.toUpperCase().hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        CaseInsensitiveString other = (CaseInsensitiveString) obj;
        if (string == null) {
            if (other.string != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!string.toUpperCase().equals(other.string.toUpperCase()))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    // Other Methods to access string
}
```